# Why can I not disable any module via the admin menu?

Tags: 7

Any module can not be disabled via admin menu (admin/modules page). This problem appeared after succesful instalation and customising site functionality.

I'm logged in as administrator, using Drupal 7. Switching off programatically seems works.

Any idea what can be a reason and how it could be solved?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access. You don't state if you get any error, nor how the module page appears you.